# how to mount share folder cifs over stunnel?(secure samba)

Tags: linux, filesystems, samba, smb, stunnel

I configure stunnel server

```
accept:0.0.0.0:800
connect:127.0.0.1:139
```

and stunnel client

```
client=yes
accept:127.0.0.1:139
connect=serverip:800
```

and try to mount with this command

```
mount -t cifs -o user=x,password=y,vers=3.0,port=139 //127.0.0.1/test /mnt/test2
```

but throw error:
No such file or directory

but smbclient work

please help me
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I change port number to 445 is solved